# How to preserve data when using the db-migrate package?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the [db-migrate](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/configuration/) npm package to manage my production and development schema for my Nodejs Server with MySQL database. I configured everything and them I realized that running `db-migrate` deletes all data. Is there a way to change schema using this package without losing all table data?

I have my migration file setup something like this at the moment

/* Callback-based version */

```
exports.up = function (db, callback) {
  db.createTable('pets', {
    id: { type: 'int', primaryKey: true },
    name: 'string'
  }, callback);
};

exports.down = function (db, callback) {
  db.dropTable('pets', callback);
};
```

Every time I change the schema I do `db-migrate down` than I do

```
db-migrate up
```

Answer (score 1):

You are losing data because your down migration script deletes the table + data. If you need to preserve the data, you should have explicit steps to make a copy before you drop / truncate a table.

You could create a database snapshot (using [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)) and reload that so that you have a "checkpoint" in which you have a copy of the data.

Alternatively, you can add a few steps in your up migration script that will create a timestamped backup table for you to reference. The way I generally do that is by:

- [renaming](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/SQL/#renametabletablename-newtablename-callback) a table to its timestamped variant
- creating a new table from the timestamped table
- backfilling the values into the new table

Its worth mentioning that db-migrate is used for keeping your application and your db schemas in sync. Dropping a table in a down migration, while the correct inverse of a table creation, has more implications for managing your code going forward. My previous technical mentor would tell me that in *most* cases, a down-migration creates more of a headache then its worth, so its best to "roll" forward with new up migrations instead. It **feels** wrong, but in practice, is a pragmatic move for when I was working with `db-migrate`, mysql, and node.js.

Comment: Can you expalin what you mean when you say roll forward with new migration? Are you saying create a new migration file?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. If you made a mistake in a migration file, or you need to make an edit, just do it in a new migration in the `up` script. There are very little downsides to this approach.